# Table Joins SQL

Tags: sql, database, join, impala

i have 4 different tables i'd need to join. i was previously doing a union all with nulls but this gave problems further down the line.
1,2 and 3 are how i want to aggregate the dataset and are common to each table.
i'm doing joins instead now, but am getting "duplicate table alias" error.
any ideas?

thanks!

```
SELECT
  A.1
  A.2
  A.3
  A.4
  B.5
  C.6
  D.7
FROM A
LEFT JOIN
 ON A.1 = B.1
 AND A.2 = B.2
 AND A.3 = B.3
LEFT JOIN
 ON A.1 = C.1
 AND A.2 = C.2
 AND A.3 = C.3
LEFT JOIN
 ON A.1 = D.1
 AND A.2 = D.2
 AND A.3 = D.3
```

Comment: Missing tables... (Between JOIN and ON...)

Comment: `A` `left join` what table? Look at any example.

Answer (score 1):

So what I added was commas after each of the selected items and then you need the table name when you want to join them together. Take a look at examples online of different joins. Hope this helps/points you in the right direction! :)

```
 SELECT
      A.1,
      A.2,
      A.3,
      A.4,
      B.5,
      C.6,
      D.7
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B
     ON A.1 = B.1
     AND A.2 = B.2
     AND A.3 = B.3
    LEFT JOIN C
     ON A.1 = C.1
     AND A.2 = C.2
     AND A.3 = C.3
    LEFT JOIN D
     ON A.1 = D.1
     AND A.2 = D.2
     AND A.3 = D.3
```